# What parameters to pass to svm function of scikit learn library for document classification

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, svm, text-classification, document-classification

I am new to Machine Learning. I am working on document classification. 
For that I am trying to train SVM on a subset of "20 newsgroup" dataset.
I am using scikit learn for this. 
link:  [SVM - Scikit Learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html)
As a training set I have taken 3 categories of news and 40 documents in each category.
For each document, I have done the following so far:

- tokenization
- removing stop words (i.e. 'the','on','in' etc.)
- lemmatization (stemming words) (i.e. 'runs','running','ran' = 'run')
- calculating tf-idf score for the remaining words

(`labels[ ]`:list containing category labels for each document)

(`final_list[ ]`: list containing list of words and their tf-idf scores for each documents. i.e.

```
final_list=[
    [['run',0.16544],['ground',0.1224]...]
    [['disk',0.9677],['pc',0.8888]....]
    .....
    .....
    ])
```

As other classifiers, SVC, NuSVC, and LinearSVC take as input two arrays:
an array X of size [n_samples, n_features] holding the training samples, 
and an array y of class labels (strings or integers), size [n_samples]:

Sample code from Scikit Learn webpage:(for numeric data)

```
>>> from sklearn import svm
>>> X = [[0, 0], [1, 1]]
>>> y = [0, 1]
>>> clf = svm.SVC()
>>> clf.fit(X, y)  
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
decision_function_shape=None, degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='rbf',
max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
tol=0.001, verbose=False)
```

After being fitted, the model can then be used to predict new values:

```
>>> clf.predict([[2., 2.]])
array([1])
```

Now when I am using the following lines:

```
>>> from sklearn import svm
>>> clf = svm.SVC()
>>> clf.fit(final_list, labels)
```

it is giving,

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

I am not sure what parameters to pass to svm function for my problem statement.

Comment: `final_list` contains lists of different sizes. Your samples have not the same features. Try to clean and format your test set

Comment: You can use `TFiDFVectorizer` on your raw input of texts